# Cerrar actividad android

Tags: android, android-studio, alertdialog

**Buenas, tengo una duda sobre cómo cerrar una `Activity` desde un `AlertDialog`. Para explicarme mejor, tengo una `Activtity` que se llama **ParteUnoCapUno** que va trayendo datos desde otras clases. Esto funciona así:

```
mensajesArrayList = new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).llenarMensajesPorID(1);
lvMensajes.setAdapter(new AdaptadorMensajes(getApplicationContext(), mensajesArrayList));
tra.timerUno(ParteUnoCapUno.this);
```

La parte `tra.timerUno(ParteUnoCapUno.this);` es la que va mostrando los **AlertDialog**, ésta es una clase. Llegado a un punto, me gustaría un `AlertDialog` que cierre la `Activity` en la que se encuentra, por lo que en la actividad hice un método:

```
public void cerrarActividad(){
        ParteUnoCapUno.this.finish();
    }
```

Y desde la clase, lo llamo así:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.game_over, null);
                        alertadd.setView(view);
                        alertadd.setNeutralButton("Cerrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                                new ParteUnoCapUno().cerrarActividad();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog mostrar = alertadd.create();
                        mostrar.show();
```

Pero, no me ha funcionado ya que la actividad no se cierra. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `finish()` pero haciendo referencia a la `Activity` en la cual se encuentra el Diálogo:

```
getActivity().finish();
```

de esta forma:

```
                alertadd.setNeutralButton("Cerrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: El `getActivity()` no sale